# Create mapping from numbers to range of unique numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array containing a lot of entries like (102, 6, 7, 192, 29...). However they repeat  often, so that there are just 32 unique numbers. What is the best way to create a mapping from the 32 unique numbers into the range 0-31. I am thinking of a function where I can feed in the array containing all the 32 different "high numbers" and I get out an array with the same length as the original but with all the values in the range of 0-31.

Comment: What did you try? Without showing your code it will be harder for others to help you. Please try to include a [mcve].

Comment: I tried it with modulo because I know the range of the numbers. However because they are far from being consecutive i.e. huge gaps between the numbers this doesn't compress into the minimal range possible. So my problem lies more in the theory on how to archive such a thing.

Comment: Okey. But actually just how to solve this mathematically would help me already. The implementation I can then figure out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Numpy [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique) function can do this, you just have to tell it to return the  indices of the unique array that can be used to reconstruct the original array. Here's a short demo, based on the example in the docs.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

# Create an array of repeated "large" values
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=20) * 11
print(a)

# Extract the sorted unique values, and the indices of the unique
# array which can be used to reconstruct the original array
u, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
print(inv)

new = u[inv]
print(new)
```

**output**

```
[33 44 22 44 44 11 22 22 22 44 33 22 44 11 33 11 33 44  0 33]
[3 4 2 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 3 2 4 1 3 1 3 4 0 3]
[33 44 22 44 44 11 22 22 22 44 33 22 44 11 33 11 33 44  0 33]
```